# How do I change the value of a text field on click?

Tags: php, javascript

I am making a calculator in PHP. One problem I have been having trouble with, is this.

```
<input type="button" name="insert" value="0" style="width: 30px; height: 35px" onClick="zeroCheck()">
```

So having a textfield containing just "0", I would like it to just replace that zero with another instead of adding another "0" onto that.

My textfield name is called entry.

I tried to develop this function in order to solve this problem to no avail.

```
function zeroCheck(){
    if (entry.value == '0'){
        entry.value=='0';
    } else{
        return entry.value+='0';
    }
}
```

This isn't doing anything at all. What am I doing wrong here?

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `entry.value=='0';` is comparision not assignment. You will have to `entry.value='0';`

Comment: Hi Twisted, if I replace that I get an "unexpected '='" error. That value can remain the same regardless, that is not a concern.

Comment: Assuming that someone types in the number `1`, should your function return `10` or `01`? If it's the former, I'm confused as to why.

Comment: @DavidThomas it will return 01. As the functions I have implemented as of now only add a value. I am unsure of how to replace a value which is the problem I am having with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is:

```
function zeroCheck(el) {
    // caching the value because it's used multiple times
    var v = el.value;
    /* setting the value with a ternary/conditional operator:
       v == '0' : testing that the value is equal to the given string
       if it is equal: the value is set to: '' + v (so there's no change),
       if it is not equal: the value is set to: '0' + v (so a zero is prepended).
    */
    el.value = ( v == '0' ? '' : '0' ) + v;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YSGGr/3/).

In the linked demo the above JavaScript is used with the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="insert" value="0" onClick="zeroCheck(this)" />
<input type="button" name="insert" value="1" onClick="zeroCheck(this)" />
<input type="button" name="insert" value="2" onClick="zeroCheck(this)" />
<input type="button" name="insert" value="3" onClick="zeroCheck(this)" />
```

To add some (basic) error-handling:

```
function zeroCheck(el) {
    // caching the value, because we're using it a few times
    var v = el.value,
    // saving the number (this way 1.4 and 1 are both preserved)
        num = parseFloat(v);

    // a basic check to see that the value is a number
    // (or rather that it is 'not Not-a-Number):
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        el.value = ( v == '0' ? '' : '0' ) + v;
    }
    else {
        // default handling here, to handle non-numeric values:
        el.value = 0;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YSGGr/2/).

Because I think I mis-read the question, I've updated this answer with another possibility, that handles sibling text-input elements and also takes into account values that already *have* a leading-zero:

```
function zeroCheck(el) {
    /* gets all the 'input' elements within the same parentNode that
       contains the button that's to be clicked: */
    var inputs = el.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    /* declaring the variables to be used in the loop, so they're not
       being constantly re-declared through the loop */
        v, num;
    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        v = inputs[i].value;
        num = parseFloat(v);

        // if the input is the button, don't do anything, just keep going
        if (inputs[i] == el) {
            continue;
        // otherwise if the number is not Not-a-Number:
        } else if (!isNaN(num)) {
            inputs[i].value = (v.charAt(0) == '0' ? '' : '0') + v;
        } else {
            inputs[i].value = 0; // error-handling
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YSGGr/5/).

Comment: +1 for an available JavaScript solution that's probably a lot more straight forward.

Comment: Ah I see how this works. Sorry, it's been a while. I'll just have to modify this solution to change around a textfield?

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed comments and JS fiddles. Very helpful :) I feel quite stupid now haha

Comment: You never have to apologise, I'm just glad to have been of some help! Oh, and don't feel stupid for not knowing, or understanding, something: that's what we're here for! But trying to put a little effort into finding an answer before you ask is about all we really expect of you (you don't have to *find* your answer, it's just we like to know you've *tried* is all). Oh, and if you find your question's been answered, please consider accepting the answer that best helped you, not necessarily *mine*, just whichever you found most helpful to your problem. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas I should really have known this information is all haha. Thanks a lot to both you and Michael for helping me get out of this rut. Hopefully everything should be smooth sailing now :) Just getting a hang of this website too but found the tick, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, because this has drastically changed from what I thought it was, let's be clear here and let's simplify this process. If the function is in PHP you're not going to be able to set, or even get for that matter, the value of the `input` control. In the PHP file you'll need to do something like this (**please note I'm assuming the `form` is a `POST`**):

```
$entryVal = $_POST["entry"];
$newEntryVal = "0";

if (trim($entryVal) != "0") {
    $newEntryVal = $newEntryVal + "0";
}
```

and then later on down in the markup:

```
<input type="text" name="entry" size="20" value = "<?= $newEntryVal ?>">
```

Comment: @HabibM, I modified the script to hopefully fix that first error (I got my languages mixed up and wrote a little JavaScript). The second, that had to change too, I didn't recognize it at first, but you need to do string concatenation not integer math.

Comment: @HabibM, what is line 58? Please edit your comment with that.

Comment: entry.value = '0';

I had this same issue when attempting this earlier

Comment: @HabibM, is this supposed to be PHP or JavaScript? How is `entry` declared (i.e. where do you set `entry` and what does that line look like)?

Comment: Sorry, here is the code for entry:   <input type="text" name="entry" size="20" value = "0">

Comment: @HabibM, OK that's good, but how is `entry` declared in the JavaScript?

Comment: I don't have any JavaScript. Should I implement javascript for this type of checking?

Comment: Sorry it's rather late in my part of town. This is purely in PHP.

Comment: @HabibM, okay, if this is PHP you're not going to be able to set the value of the `input` element from the PHP code -the PHP code runs server-side. I will give you a couple options as an edit.

Comment: I thought this would have been the problem. I'm pretty rusty in PHP. Sorry for consuming a lot of your time and thank you kindly in advance for your options in the edit.

Comment: @HabibM, oops, got my `:` and `=` mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of things are missing.
Here is the correct code:

```
function zeroCheck(){
var entry = document.getElementsByName("entry")[0];
    if (entry.value == '0'){
       entry.value = parseInt('0');
   } else {
      entry.value += parseInt('0');

   }
}
```

there is no need of return and you are using `==` in that should be `=` to assign the value.
And one more question to you is that what you want to do with `entry.value += '0';` code.

Comment: @HabibM which is your line number 57.

Comment: Thanks miss poo, I am receiving an error: unexpected T_VAR error on 
       entry.value = parseInt('0');

Answer (score 0):

Its better to give an id to your input:

```
<input type="button" id="someid" name="insert" value="0" style="width: 30px; height: 35px" onClick="zeroCheck()">

function zeroCheck(){
var entry = document.getElementById("someid");
    if (entry.value == '0'){
       entry.value = '0';
   } else {
      entry.value += '0';

   }
}
```

Comment: read the question properly OP wants the value of textfield and your code will get the value of button type how?

Comment: how is this different from your solution?

Comment: OP wants the textfields value which name is entry as he told. and you are taking the id of button field check again